# É possível votar para excluir uma pergunta de baixa qualidade?

Tags: suporte, perguntas, fechamento

Eu sei que podemos votar para fechar uma pergunta fora de contexto ou muito ampla. Mas é possível votar para remover uma pergunta do site? Ou somente os moderadores têm essa capacidade?

Comment: Tem essa outra pergunta [relaciconada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/662/qual-a-maneira-correta-de-analisar-publicacoes-de-baixa-qualidade)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para uma pergunta poder ser excluída pelos usuários comuns, primeiro ela precisa ser fechada. Uma vez fechada, usuários com privilégios suficientes podem votar para removê-la do site:

- acesso às ferramentas de moderador (atualmente 2.000, num site "graduado" 10.000): pode votar para excluir perguntas desde que elas:

  1. Possuam pontuação `-3` ou inferior; e:
  2. Pelo menos 2 dias tenham se passado.
- usuário confiável (atualmente 4.000, num site graduado 20.000): mesmo caso acima, mas pode votar imdiatamente após o fechamento - não precisa esperar 2 dias (mas ainda precisa ter `-3`).

  - Além disso, esses usuários também podem votar para remover **respostas** com pontuação `-1` ou inferior.

Comment: Agora que eu fui ver sobre isso na página de privilégios: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível. No momento enquanto estamos em beta público as limitações são as que podem ser encontradas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).